# Animation of Bootstrap Progress has Incorrect Scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of Bootstrap 2.3 progress bars which show async file reads, and are animated by updating their CSS properties using jQuery. The issue that I'm having is that the scale is wrong, so that for example when the progress approaches 100%, only about a third of the bar is displayed:

[image]

Since the math is correct (for instance in the image, we are in fact 94% into the process), I'm wondering how the proportions are off.  The HTML (I've tried with and without the `aria` values):

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" 
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding JS:

```
// ... grab the bar element as a jQuery object
var progPercent = ((currentChunk + 1) / chunks) * 100;
$bar.css('width', progPercent).attr('aria-valuenow', progPercent);
console.log($bar.width()); // shows correct percentage
$bar.text($bar.width() + '%'); // text is correct
```

What's wrong here? ;-).

Comment: Any demo or jsfiddle for us to review?

Comment: If you set a width in css with no unit. By default, the value will be interpreted in pixels. So, this mean, your `width: 94;` is the same as `width: 94px;`. Please be sure to add the unit explicitly as @Alp suggested: `$bar.css('width', progPercent+'%')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tiny mistake:

add a % sign after value for the width style value as follows:

```
$(".bar").css('width', progPercent+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', progPercent);
```

Here is a [fiddle that you can play with](https://jsfiddle.net/qw04sjhb/)

Comment: I would add that by default (if no unit is provided), value is displayed in pixels (px). So in your case, 94 mean 94px.

Comment: @Pierre-Chanel I think you meant to add your valuable comment to the question, not to my answer. If I am right, please do so because I see a value in your comment.It could be useful for whoever reads the question above and could be easily get missed if it stayed here. Thank you for your insight.